# Java code to check sdcard exsist in android device

Tags: java, android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am developing an android application and I need to know how could i check if the sdcard exist or not before exporting a file to it , so that i could notify the user that the sdcard is or isn't mounted.

Comment: Are you talking about the removable SDCard ?

Comment: well jamoBox just answered me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean hasSDCard() {
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()
              .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not universal, for example it returns true on my Nexus 4, which has NO SD card. See the docs for getExternalStorageState() here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()